# google drive cache taking too much space

Tags: windows-10, mac, storage, google-drive-file-stream

I recently found that google drive is taking too much space (50GB) although I only made 3GB available offline. 
On my Mac and PC I had too go and delete the cache folder. 
Is there a way to avoid it? I don't have such issues with dropbox

Comment: Are you using Google Drive File Stream?

Comment: Yes I am using google drive file stream